# FFMpeg Looping Background video and overlay

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay two videos. My first input video 20 mins long and my second input 1 minute long background video. I'm overlaying them successfully but when i try to play it after 1 min (when my second input background video is over) both of my videos are freezing and audio keeps playing. How can i loop my second input until my first input is finished.

Here my code :

```
ffmpeg -i clip.mp4 -i motion_bg.mp4 
-filter_complex "
     [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1280x720 [lowerleft];
     [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080[center];
     [center][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=360
"
-c:v libx264 -c:a copy overlay_test.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

The BG needs to be looped. At present, you can use the movie filter and set the loop option.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i clip.mp4 -f lavfi -i movie=motion_bg.mp4:loop=0 
-filter_complex "
     [0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1280x720 [lowerleft];
     [1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1920x1080[center];
     [center][lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=360
"
-c:v libx264 -c:a copy overlay_test.mp4
```